# inexplicable syntax error when I write one code from the documentation

Tags: aql, query-by-example

I have a newbie problem with the syntax. I've just started learning AQL. The documentation is good but I keep making a syntax error that I can´t explain.

I tried doing exactly the same as the documentation says; I copied the same thing with the same collection as the example and that worked, but when I try writing the same thing, the syntax checker in the web interface blocks me.

Maybe I'm writing something more that I can´t see like a format code in the word? (I didn´t copy anything from a text processor). I'm using Firefox and Windows 10

!(https://ibb.co/fYyCNwK)

(This is almost the first page of the newbie manual)

```sql
INSERT {
    "name": "Ned",
    "surname": "Stark",
    "alive"; true,
    "age": 41,
    "traits": ["A","H","C","N","P"]
} INTO Characters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semi-colon (`;`) between `"alive"` and `true`.

This should be a colon (`:`).

You have:

```
"alive"; true,
```

You should have:

```
"alive": true,
```

The syntax error is helpful, it reports:

- `unexpected`
- `near '; true,`
- `at position 4:12` (this corresponds to line|row #4 and column #12 and your `;`)

Comment: thanks Daz... how embarrasing, but in my defense i am mole, so is a normal struggle in my day.